# I import uuid in my react typescript, Got an id error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

**I got red line or error in id , i import uuid in my react typescript file,here is my code **

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const handleAddUser = () => {
    setValues({ name: '', email: '' });
    dispatch(addUser({
      id : uuidv4(),
      name:values.name,
      email:values.email
    }));
    navigate('/');
  };
```

error -

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    18 |     setValues({ name: '', email: '' });
    19 |     dispatch(addUser({
  > 20 |       id : uuidv4(),
       |       ^^
    21 |       name:values.name,
    22 |       email:values.email
    23 |     }));
```

help and solve the id error please

Comment: What is unclear about that error? `addUser` expects `id` to be a `number`, but an `uuid` is a `string`

Answer (score 0):

The id field in your Redux store or actions is expected to be of type 'number', while the uuidv4() function from the uuid library returns a string.
Thats why there is a mismatch between the expected type of the id field and the actual value you're trying to assign to it.
To resolve this, you will need to ensure consistency between the expected type of the id field (which should be string) and the value you're providing from the uuidv4() function (which is a string). This might involve updating type declarations in your Redux-related files or making sure your reducers, action creators, and store definitions are correctly handling string id values.